# How to manage add-ins in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

i have (at least) two addins installed in Visual Studio (2010 (Professional)). i would like to temporarily disable them.

How can i manage addins in Visual Studio 2010?

---

i tried using the **Add-in Manager** (Tools -> Add-in Manager...):

[image]

But neither of my (at least) two addins appear.

How can i manage addins in Visual Studio 2010?

---

Looking at MSDN:

> ### [How to: Deactivate and Remove an Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228765.aspx)
>
> When you finish using an add-in, you can unload it from Visual Studio by clearing the check box next to its name in Add-in Manager.
>
> By following the steps in this topic, you can remove the add-in permanently so that it no longer appears in Add-in Manager and its command no longer appears on the Tools menu or the Visual Studio toolbar.
>
> The Add-in Manager is located on the Tools menu.

Comment: Have you looked at Tools->Extension Manager? Are these 'addins' installed there?

Comment: @Steve Why yes, yes they are. Phrase that in the form of an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, Microsoft has added another form of 'addins' (how we used to call them).
Now, we have the `Visual Studio Integration Package` that are not COM based like addins.
This has prompted the creation of a different menu where you handle these kind of extensions.
The main menu is still `Tools` but a specific submenu called `Extension Manager` has been added

More information on this argument could be found here

["Visual Studio Integration Package" vs "Visual Studio Add-in": what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139294/visual-studio-integration-package-vs-visual-studio-add-in-what-is-the-diffe)

and here

[Differences between Visual Studio 2010 add-in manager and extension manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758244/differences-between-visual-studio-2010-add-in-manager-and-extension-manager)